# Submenues making the nav mennu to come down

Tags: html, css

I have a simple nav bar made with HTML Lists.

The structure is like this at the first:

```
<div id="menu">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">My Profile</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Inbox</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Notifications</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
 </div>
```

Then when I add submenu it is like this:

```
<div id="menu">
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li>
            <a href="#">My Profile</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">My Questions</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
            <li><a href="#">Inbox</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Notifications</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
 </div>
```

But the problem is that it ruins the whole look of the menu. See the CSS below:

```
#menu {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 5%;
}

#menu nav ul li {
    display: inline;
    padding: 5px;
}

#menu nav ul li a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 2px;
}

#menu nav ul li a:hover {
    background: #eee;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 1px #000;
}

#menu nav ul li ul li {
    display: block;
}
```

How can I solve this issue?

[See](http://jsfiddle.net/tQhfg/) what I have done.

This is what I want:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can make the submenu `position: absolute` to take it out of the main flow, and allow the parent list items display properly inline.

Since the positioning of absolute positioned elements is relative the their first relatively positioned parent, to get the submenu to line up vertically you can set the submenu's parent `<li>` to `position:relative` to ensure that any absolutely positioned children (like the submenu) will be positioned relative to that element. Then it's just a matter of setting the submenu to `left:0` to ensure it stays at the left side of the parent.

The code below will take the submenus and align them vertically beneath the parent list item's text:

```
#menu nav > ul{
    position: relative;
}

#menu nav > ul ul{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6Qtbj/2/

Comment: how can I align them vertically?

Comment: what do you mean by aligned horizontally? To ensure that the submenus have enough space, you'll need to set the parent <li> to a wide enough width to accommodate for the width of the submenu. Is that what you're referring to?

Comment: you aligned them vertically, i wanted to align them horizontally! sorry for my mistake that I told you to align them vertically :/

Comment: NO! They should come in a seprate line but in a vertical manner!

Comment: ahhh, gotcha. All you need to do is remove display:block from the '#menu nav ul li ul li' selector so that the <li> elements of the submenu appear inline as well. The fiddle in my answer should be updated.

Comment: i'm confused then, how do you want the menu items to appear?

Comment: See, the main menu items should appear horizontally but the sub items should appear vertically!

Answer (score 0):

Is this 'inline-block' layering helping :

```
#menu nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

[fiddled here](http://jsfiddle.net/tQhfg/1/)